# Extract 1st 2nd 3rd values till nth value from hyphenated string column in SQL Server table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, split

Table has values like `12-43-5765-234-56-24-6456-234-678-9-0-0` with hyphens

I need to take the first value as a separate column and 2nd value as separate column and so on.

I tried like this.

```
DECLARE @S VARCHAR(MAX);
SET @S = '12-43-5765-234-56-24-6456-234-678-9-0-0'

SELECT SUBSTRING(@S, 0, CHARINDEX('-', @S)) AS first
```

This above query selects only first value, but how can 4th and fifth value can be extracted from string? like

```
12 as first,
43 as second,
5765 as third,
234 as fourth,
56 as fifth,
24 as sixth and so on..
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a maximum (or known) number of positions, and **DON'T** want to go dynamic

**Example**

```
DECLARE @S VARCHAR(MAX);
SET @S='12-43-5765-234-56-24-6456-234-678-9-0-0'


Select Pos1 = xDim.value('/x[1]','varchar(max)') --could change to desired datatype (int ?)
      ,Pos2 = xDim.value('/x[2]','varchar(max)') 
      ,Pos3 = xDim.value('/x[3]','varchar(max)')
      ,Pos4 = xDim.value('/x[4]','varchar(max)')
      ,Pos5 = xDim.value('/x[5]','varchar(max)')
      ,Pos6 = xDim.value('/x[6]','varchar(max)')
      ,Pos7 = xDim.value('/x[7]','varchar(max)')
      ,Pos8 = xDim.value('/x[8]','varchar(max)')
      ,Pos9 = xDim.value('/x[9]','varchar(max)')
      ,Pos10= xDim.value('/x[10]','varchar(max)')
      ,Pos11= xDim.value('/x[11]','varchar(max)')
      ,Pos12= xDim.value('/x[12]','varchar(max)')
      ,Pos13= xDim.value('/x[13]','varchar(max)')
 From  (Select Cast('<x>' + replace(@S,'-','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml) as xDim) as A
```

**Returns**

[image]